# Frobenius norm of a correlation matrix as a measure of intraindividual variability

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, panel-data, variability

In APA-ATI Analysis of Intensive Longitudinal Data: Experience Sampling and Ecological Momentary Assessment
(link: https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/APA-ATI_ILD_Session_E_-_IntraVarMetricsComputation.html), authors present Frobenius Norm as a measure which can be used to identify intraindividual variability in multivariate time-series (longitudinal data for each id).

Authors present the following code to be calculated in R as :

istat_iFnorm <- ddply(AMIB_daily_sub[ ,vars], "id",
function(x) {
norm(cor(x[,-1],use="pairwise.complete.obs",
method="pearson"),type="F")} )

so for each id, frobenius norm of correlation matrix is calculated.

Could some explain what does the value of Frobenius norm convey and how it can be used to compare the individuals in terms of their longitudinal pattern?